# Windows: Anaconda base environment automatically gets activated whenever terminal is opened

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

Whenever I open my terminal, the base conda environment gets activated like below:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\surya>
```

And I used to run `conda deactivate` to come out of conda. Even tried removing conda related PATH variables but doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by setting the below config. Run this command after opening the terminal as Administrator.

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Then restart the terminal for the changes to be effective. The config can be verified by running `conda config --show`